getYouTubeThumbnail function not returning the correct thumbnail URL?
I wrote a function to extract the video ID from a YouTube URL and return the corresponding thumbnail image URL. However, the function doesn’t seem to be working as expected.


const getYouTubeThumbnail = (url: string) => {
  const videoId = url.split("v=")[1];
  return https://img.youtube.com/vi/${videoId}/hqdefault.jpg;
};



When I pass a YouTube video URL like https://www.youtube.com/watch?v=-jz8mrwU_Fc&ab_channel=10Alytics, I expect to get https://img.youtube.com/vi/dQw4w9WgXcQ/hqdefault.jpg, but instead, it seems to either not work or return an incorrect URL.
What am I doing wrong? Is there a better way to extract the video ID?
the function above but it doesn’t work as intended

I see dQw in the url I know it's rickroll. And I like it

Your getYouTubeThumbnail function works as intended with regular youtube links, however it may run into problems when extra params are added after the videoID.
Using url.split("v=")[1] retrieves the portion of the URL that comes after "v=".


const getYouTubeThumbnail = (url: string) => {
  const videoId = url.split("v=")[1]?.split("&")[0]; // Gets the part after "v=" and splits by "&" to remove additional parameters
  return `https://img.youtube.com/vi/${videoId}/hqdefault.jpg`;
};



by applying .split("&")[0], it separates any additional parameters that may follow the video ID and captures only the first segment, ensuring that you obtain just the video ID.

Splitting on v= gives you not just the v value, but everything after it in the URL.
i.e. Splitting https://www.youtube.com/watch?v=-jz8mrwU_Fc&ab_channel=10Alytics gets you -jz8mrwU_Fc&ab_channel=10Alytics.
I suggest the following as more robust:
const videoId = new URL(url).searchParams.get('v');

